# Where is OpenStruct#attributes coming from? Or how can I find where how a method has been added?

Tags: ruby

I have a gemfile that includes activerecord, therefore I have `.attributes` which I can call on my model instances to convert them to hashes.

Through a mix up in my code I ended up passing a OpenStruct instead of a model into one of my methods and got a hard-to-find bug. The cause was that OpenStruct#attributes was returning nil (and not throwing an error, which would have alerted me to the problem).

I have no idea how OpenStruct#attributes is being defined.

> [2] pry(main)> show-source OpenStruct#attributes
>
> Error: Couldn't locate a definition for OpenStruct#attributes!

...

> (byebug) OpenStruct.new.method(:attributes)
>
> *** NameError Exception: undefined method 'attributes' for class `OpenStruct'

...

> (byebug) OpenStruct.new.attributes
>
> nil

How can I find what this method's source code is and how it's being included?

I have a hunch that it's being done with method-missing somewhere, that's why it's so hard to track down. But is it possible to do so?

Comment: Are you asking about [`attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods.html#method-i-attributes)' source code?

Comment: @AndreyDeineko why has this been defined on OpenStruct? that's my question; I'm familiar with the activerecord method

Comment: @ndn How can I tell which method missing, considering I'm loading a bunch of gems and not defining one myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clearify a bit, it's not a new method (though it behaves like one).

In ruby 2.4 I inspected, `method_missing` in `ostruct.rb` handles call like `attr=` and `attr` without defining new methods. Some classes do define method on first use, but `OpenStruct` is not one of them.

Answer (score 3):

If you can't get it with `#method`, it's `#method_missing`. And that is a method like any else, so you can find the source the same way:

```
OpenStruct.instance_method(:method_missing).source_location
  # => ["/Users/wink/.rbenv/versions/2.3.3/lib/ruby/2.3.0/ostruct.rb", 189]
```

[Link to Github](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/lib/ostruct.rb#L197-L214)

Comment: Oh, this is so obvious now that I think about it. Of course open struct uses method missing, it's just like Javascript in that regard - looking up a nonexistent key returns nil.

Answer (score 1):

The method `attributes` is not defined on the [`OpenStruct`](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.4.0/libdoc/ostruct/rdoc/OpenStruct.html), it is just how `method_missing` works.